# Location of OpenGL module when using Qt

Tags: qt, opengl

I am new to using OpenGL with Qt Creator and I have been playing around with the information I got from various tutorials. However, I never was able to find out where the OpenGL function definitions actually are!

I was thinking that when I linked the opengl module to the qmake file like this:

```
QT += core gui opengl
```

the OpenGL stuff was included, but then I thought again when I was reading about the QGLWidget.

So where does the OpenGL API become included into my code?

P.S. My OS is Windows 7 and I my graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 6250 Graphics.

Comment: Pls add info about your OS and GPU. Its relevant.

Comment: Do you need those declarations for autocompletion or for learning what OpenGL you can use with Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QT variable is used to include Qt modules into your project. By adding opengl you're adding the Qt OpenGL module which contains Qt code that uses OpenGL (and links to it). If by "include" you mean link, than the OpenGL module of Qt (libQtOpenGL.so) links the various OpenGL libraries. Also, the Qt module includes the headers of the Qt OpenGL module which in turn includes OpenGL headers.

The OpenGL headers and the OpenGL libraries are wherever your OS keeps those. Your project knows where those are because of the Qt mkspecs for your platform, whatever it is. In the mkspecs, include paths and link paths are already included.

For instance, now I'm on a Mac OS X, and Qt mkspecs are installed in /usr/local/Qt4.8/mkspecs. Here I have all the platform descriptions, under common you can find mac.conf, which is a part of the description of my platform. Inside it you can see:

```
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL = /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers \
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers/
```

This information is used when Qt Creator (qmake) is asked to produce a Makefile for any application. This way your application knows where to find the headers for OpenGL. Your project will automatically add that to the include paths only when you add the opengl module.

As another example, this is part of the definition for the Linux platform:

```
...
QMAKE_INCDIR          =
QMAKE_LIBDIR          =
QMAKE_INCDIR_X11      = /usr/X11R6/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11      = /usr/X11R6/lib
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT       = $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]
QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT       = $$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS]
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL   = /usr/X11R6/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL   = /usr/X11R6/lib
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES1 = $$QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES1 = $$QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $$QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $$QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL
QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL      = 
QMAKE_LIBDIR_EGL      =
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENVG   = 
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENVG   =
...
```

I suppose you can understand on your own what this means ;-)

So to answer your question: the include paths and the link paths to the OpenGL libraries are included into the Makefile qmake produces for your application taking the information stored in the mkspec file which is located somewhere in your system. The actual OpenGL headers and libraries are located in a default location in your system, and this has nothing to do with Qt itself. You might need to include the headers in your source code if you use OpenGL libraries directly (or you might not need, it depends), but the include paths should already be provided by your mkspec files.

EDIT: Look what happens automatically when adding the opengl module: this is the command line Qt Creator uses to compile a C++ file without the opengl module (on Mac):

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.8/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I../TextEdit -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include -I. -I. -I../TextEdit -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o main.o ../TextEdit/main.cpp
```

now this is what happens after adding it:

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Qt4.8/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I../TextEdit -I/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/Library/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/include/QtOpenGL -I/usr/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -I../TextEdit -I. -F/Library/Frameworks -o main.o ../TextEdit/main.cpp
```

Your project has been told where to look for the OpenGL headers.

Comment: Cool, what's the difference between linking with `QT += opengl` and including the libQtOpenGL? Is that the same as QtOpenGL or QGLWidget headers?

Comment: I don't understand what "including" means here. You don't "include" a library. QGLWidget is a class which is located in the Qt OpenGL module. You shouldn't be able to use it without the OpenGL module, which is added with QT += opengl.

Comment: Makes much more sense. So the functions in the OpenGL files that I know of like `glShadeModel()` and `glHint()` are all able to be used once I link the `QT += opengl` because they are in the QGLWidget?

Comment: Not exactly. The QGLWidget is just a widget which sets up what you need to draw using OpenGL. The function glShadeModel() is an OpenGL function, and it is located where it always is, in the gl.h header. Adding the opengl module makes your project aware of where to find those headers on your platform and to link to the OpenGL libraries, so you don't have to do it yourself. Anyway, the QGLWidget header includes gl.h, so by including QGLWidget in your sources you might not need to include gl.h by yourself again. But that is secondary.

Comment: I added another note to show what happens when you add the opengl module.

Answer (score 1):

Qt do not contain OpenGL API definition. It must be present in OS already (usually bundled with GPU driver).

Look for documentation of your gpu driver or OS docs.

Comment: So does this mean that when I add `QT += opengl` to the .pro file, the Qt project becomes linked with the OpenGL stuff and I can call all the functions and other good stuff?

Comment: Nope. It just mean that you can call ANY OpenGL calls that are present in Operating System. This code just indicate what are you using from Qt in your project (Qt is biiiigggggg).

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. So does the `QT += opengl` link the project to the OpenGL functions and other stuff?

Comment: Nope. 1) During compilation Qt will look for OpenGL API declarations present in your Operating System. 2) During runtime your calls will be directed to dll in your Operating System. If you want to read OpenGL API go for OpenGL specification.

Answer (score -1):

Try "GLEW", "glut", "GLU", and "GL" instead of "opengl", I'm not sure how it works with Qt Creator, but these are linker flags for opengl.

Comment: yes, technically it isn't, however I haven't heard anybody used glut or GLU without opengl ;-)

Comment: But still Qt can bundle glut/GLU but not OpenGL. Update your answer with that info.

Comment: I'm sure your comment will do, thanks for pointing that out ;)